# tengo problemas para reproducir este video

Tags: html

estoy estructurado mi proxima pagina web asi que decidir buscar un video, Ojo soy principiante!!,
este es el codigo, estoy usando SublimeText 3 como entorno de desarrollo , pero aun asi poniendo el atributo autoplay y loop no se reproduce

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
    <head>
    <title>video</title>
         </head>
       <body>
      <video src="video.mp4" autoplay 
         loop></video>

     </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: El video está en el mismo directorio que el html o dentro de una carpeta? Puedes agregar la estructura de tu directorio?

Comment: Dale f12 si no estas en portatil y ve a la sección consola, mira si te aparece un error que diga que no se pudo cargar el recurso, ¿o tu vez el video en pantalla pero no se reproduce?

Comment: por cierto creo que deberias agregarle un atributo controls a tu etiqueta video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La etiqueta **source** va dentro de la etiqueta **video**.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay loop>
  <source src="video.mp4">
</video>
```

Te recomiendo agregarle el tag **controls** para que el reproductor tenga los controles básicos (pausa, volumen, etc.) y también verifica que *video.mp4* esté en el directorio raíz de tu proyecto.

Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias su comentario me fue muy util

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos puntos en tu código:

1. Como los otros usuarios te marcan, la etiqueta `source` va dentro de la etiqueta `video`:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay loop>
<!-- El atributo controls es útil a menos que por una cuestion de tu desarrollo precises que no se vean -->
  <source src="video.mp4">
</video>
```

2. Lo segundo que te va a pasar es que no te va a reproducir automáticamente ya que, si bien agregaste el atributo `autoplay`, los navegadores no permiten que inicien si no tienen ademas el atributo `muted` (que quita el sonido). Esto es para evitar los videos automáticos y generalmente molestos.